# android horizontal gridview

Tags: android, gridview

How can I make grid view to display it's items in this order ?[image]

I've tried two-way-gridview, but it doesn't work properly. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered dynamically re-setting the grid items based on landscape/portrait?

Comment: @user1282637 actually, this is not the problem of screen orientation. Check [this](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/grid-lists.html), it's talking about 2 kinds of layout, but I'm not sure if this can be applied to grid view.